# Using FullCalendar, jQuery, and MVC to view data from database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I'm a newbie in using fullCalendar to renderEvents from a database. My purpose is to display a calendar with booking details of my hotel. The calendar will only display the data.

Here's the original script. I don't know where should I put the calling event to call the data from database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // DO NOT REMOVE : GLOBAL FUNCTIONS!

    $(document).ready(function () {

        "use strict";

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var hdr = {
            left: 'title',
           center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
          right: 'prev,today,next'
        };

        var initDrag = function (e) {
            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end

            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim(e.children().text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                description: $.trim(e.children('span').attr('data-description')),
                icon: $.trim(e.children('span').attr('data-icon')),
                className: $.trim(e.children('span').attr('class')) // use the element's children as the event class
            };
            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            e.data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            e.draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
            });
        };

        var addEvent = function (title, priority, description, icon) {
            title = title.length === 0 ? "Untitled Event" : title;
            description = description.length === 0 ? "No Description" : description;
            icon = icon.length === 0 ? " " : icon;
            priority = priority.length === 0 ? "label label-default" : priority;

            var html = $('<li><span class="' + priority + '" data-description="' + description + '" data-icon="' +
                icon + '">' + title + '</span></li>').prependTo('ul#external-events').hide().fadeIn();

            $("#event-container").effect("highlight", 800);

            initDrag(html);
        };

        /* initialize the external events
         -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events > li').each(function () {
            initDrag($(this));
        });

        $('#add-event').click(function () {
            var title = $('#title').val(),
                priority = $('input:radio[name=priority]:checked').val(),
                description = $('#description').val(),
                icon = $('input:radio[name=iconselect]:checked').val();

            addEvent(title, priority, description, icon);
        });

        /* initialize the calendar
         -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


            header: hdr,
            buttonText: {
                prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
            },

           // defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!

            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            },

            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    }, true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            events: [{
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                description: 'long description',
                className: ["event", "bg-color-greenLight"],
                icon: 'fa-check'
            }, {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                className: ["event", "bg-color-red"],
                icon: 'fa-lock'
            }, {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false,
                className: ["event", "bg-color-blue"],
                icon: 'fa-clock-o'
            }, {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false,
                className: ["event", "bg-color-blue"],
                icon: 'fa-clock-o'
            }, {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false,
                className: ["event", "bg-color-darken"]
            }, {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false,
                className: ["event", "bg-color-darken"]
            }, {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false,
                className: ["event", "bg-color-darken"]
            }, {
                title: 'Smartadmin Open Day',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                className: ["event", "bg-color-darken"]
            }],

            eventRender: function (event, element, icon) {
                if (!event.description == "") {
                    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/><span class='ultra-light'>" + event.description +
                        "</span>");
                }
                if (!event.icon == "") {
                    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<i class='air air-top-right fa " + event.icon +
                        " '></i>");
                }
            },

            windowResize: function (event, ui) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
            }
        });

        /* hide default buttons */
        $('.fc-header-right, .fc-header-center').hide();


        $('#calendar-buttons #btn-prev').click(function () {
            $('.fc-button-prev').click();
            return false;
        });

        $('#calendar-buttons #btn-next').click(function () {
            $('.fc-button-next').click();
            return false;
        });

        $('#calendar-buttons #btn-today').click(function () {
            $('.fc-button-today').click();
            return false;
        });

        $('#mt').click(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
        });

        $('#ag').click(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
        });

        $('#td').click(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
        });

    })

</script>
```

}

Comment: you can add your location from where to fetch the events from database in JSON format using events callback of fullcalendar.

Comment: hi @SauravDangol, do you have any example on how to do that? I'm really lost. Thanx a lot.

Comment: Will this help?
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, thanx for the reminder. I really have no idea at all about this .... that's why I posted the original code....I don't know where to start.....    :(

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://www.jqueryajaxphp.com/fullcalendar-crud-with-jquery-and-php/) helped me.

Basically you need to have a table to store id,start,end, title of each event.
You then need to json encode the data you retrieve from the table and feed it to your calendar via Ajax.

Comment: thanx for the suggestions. btw, do i really need to create a new table for each event? is it possible if i just call it from my booking table?

Comment: You create the table once and then add records (events) to the table as needed.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have your events defined as a static array via the `events` property of the calendar, as defined when you set up the calendar using the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar...` code. To get dynamic data, such as from a remote server, you have two main options, as shown in the fullCalendar docs.

1) "events" as a JSON feed: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

With this option you simply specify the URL of a resource which will return events in the format that fullCalendar expects, and can filter the events by time period using the parameters that fullCalendar automatically sends it.

You can specify the feed as simply as this:

```
events: '/myfeed.php'
```

It will need to be able to respond to two GET parameters, `start` and `end` and filter the returned list based on these dates. The documentation above gives an example of what the parameter values might look like.

There are a few more options available to you if required, but again the documentation explains these very well.

2) "events" as a function: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

Essentially here you can do whatever you like to retrieve the data - probably it will involve an ajax call, but there might be some customisation involved, or you can process the events client-side a bit before you return them to fullCalendar. It's really up to you. But essentially you define events as a function like:

```
events: myGetEventsFunction
```

and then you can provide a callback function with the parameters given in the above documentation:

```
function myGetEventsFunction(start, end, timezone, callback) {
...
```

You are provided with `start` and `end` which will correspond to the date range currently being displayed on the calendar, a timezone if you need it, and `callback`, which is a function that you use to return the events to fullCalendar - again, see the above docs for a detailed example of how to use it.

Either of these options will cause the code to run every time the user changes the calendar view, or changes the date range.

Comment: hi @ADyson, if I were to choose the second option, and if i'm using mvc c#...i should put the function myGetEventsFunction in my controller right?
then, call it in the $('#calendar').fullCalendar? That's all right? or is there any other setting needs to be done?

Comment: myGetEventsFunction would be a JavaScript function. It would then need to use ajax to call a C# method in your controller. Equally you could do the same using the first option, as long as the C# method accepts the parameters specified in the docs and returns the data in the correct JSON format. The second option just gives you a bit more flexibility, in case you want to return other data at the same time, or you have an existing server-side method for returning events, but which doesn't meet the fullCalendar spec - then you can use the custom function as an intermediary to transform the data.